# How to write string in each line in txt file apart from the first one

Tags: python

I want to iterate through all txt files in a folder and add string to each line but the first one.

I have now:

> a|b|c|d|e|f
>
> 1|2|3|4|5

I want to add e.g. 'X'

> a|b|c|d|e|f
>
> X|1|2|3|4|5

```
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path

cwd = os.getcwd()

directory = cwd

output = cwd

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    cpath =(Path(txt_file).resolve().stem)
  
    nametxt = "-".join(cpath.split('_')[0:1])
    amendtext = "|  " + nametxt

    src=open(txt_file, errors='ignore')

    lines = src.read().splitlines()
    src.close

    src = open(txt_file, "w")
    src.write('\n'.join([amendtext +line for line in lines]))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided sample input and output. Your description alone is a bit confusing and not completely clear.

Comment: I don't see any effort to avoid adding to the first line. Why did you think this would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
src.write('\n'.join([line for line in lines[:1]]+[amendtext +line for line in lines[1:]]))
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
src.write('\n'.join([amendtext +line for i,line in enumerate(lines) if i>0 ]))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to use `lines[1:]` as opposed to `i, line in enumerate(lines) if i > 0` ?

Comment: yup, A better way indeed

Comment: Yes, but it reads all the lines but first, however it also omits the first line in the final file.